# Undefined reference to member of parent class

Tags: c++, static, constexpr, member, undefined-reference

I'm desparately trying to figure out what my compiler or linker can't build my project. I have a class that derives from another class and tries to access an array that is declared static constexpr in the parent class. But somehow I get the error "undefined reference to "CParent::m_array"

Here's some example code. Please consider it pseudo code as it does not do anything useful but focuses on the problem:

```
// parent.hpp
class CParent
{
protected:
    static constexpr float m_array[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
}


// child.hpp
#include "parent.hpp"
class CChild final : public CParent
{
public:
    SomeFunction();

}

//child.cpp
#include "child.hpp"
void CChild::SomeFunction(void)
{
    if (CParent::m_array[3] == 5)
        turn_on_lead()

    return 0;
}
```

I think the code is actually correct and the problem is the linker. I'm using Cube IDE from ST which basically is eclipse. If I add the path to the debug folder which holds all the compiled *.o files to the linker via project properties -> C/C++ Build-> Settings -> MCU G++ Linker -> Libraries -> Library search path (-L), the error doesn't change at all.

Here are all 5 errors I get:
Core/Src/Child.o: in function `SomeFunction()`:
link errors found, deleteing executable 'test.elf'
mae *** [makefile:80: test.elf] Error 1
mode armelf
undefined reference to `CParent::m_array`

Any help would be highly appreciate. I'm stuck with this for hours now :-/

Thanks!

Comment: `Class` with a capital C is not standard C++. Also, `child.cpp` should probably define `CChild::SomeFunction` instead.

Comment: The capital C thing is more our own coding style. You're right about the latter. I have it like that in my sources and fixed it in the initial post

Comment: You should probably edit your question with the underlying version of G++, because I suspect it is ancient.

Comment: Any more deatils about your suspicion? I'm running GNU11 (ISO C11 + gnu extensions)

Comment: No, we need the version of your g++ compiler, not the version of C(?) you are targeting.

Comment: Allright. fixed the capital C thing
I was a little quick on the compiler thing. It's a GNU++14 ... I can and probably should use the GNU++17 though .... which reduces the errors to the 'mode armelf' one ???

Comment: To find out the version of your compiler, you may call it in a console with `g++ --version`. [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0e8c58aca919661) The compiler version and the required C++ version are two different things. The compiler version tells about the compiler (software) version, the C++ (standard) version is what you request with the command line argument `-std=`.

Comment: No, that is the _language_ version. We need the _compiler_ version.

Comment: I can't find the compiler software version, BUT I found an "update toolchain" button, clicked it, and guess what: It works now! Is that some kind of known issue with old G++ versions or how did you came to that suggestion? 

Thanks a lot! You just kept me going!

Comment: Just a hunch. Your code was correct and embedded toolchains have a tendency to ship ancient compiler versions that may not have all the bugfixes or language support that modern ones do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the compiler version. I ran Help -> Check for Update and updated the toolchain.

Thanks to Botje and Scheff's Cat for the suggestion regarding compiler version.
And of course thanks to EVERYONE who took the time to read and answer! Really appreciate it!